# Error message when MailMerge is run with documents in an Amazon Workspace

Tags: vba, amazon-web-services, ms-word, mailmerge

I have an Access database that was created a long time ago by someone else.  It's used in a Mail Merge process to create unique Word documents based on the state in question.

I has been run from the user's C:\ drive and has worked great for years.

We are now tasked with moving the the database and documents to an Amazon WorkSpace which has been set up as a shared drive (Z:).  We have gone through all of the documents and replace the C:\ drive path with the shared drive path.

When we run it in the Amazon WorkSpace, we are getting a "field calculated error in record 1" message.  We have tried using both "Z:" and the exact name "123C548eS.com" and get the same error message each time.

We have checked, double checked, and triple checked and are absolutely sure the path is correct and not the issue in the MailMerge code.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Is there something with MailMerge in Amazon WorkSpaces?  Do we need to change the code?

Thanks for the help.  I didn't show the code because it works from the C:\ drive and the path is correct.  Not sure what the issue can be.  Thanks again for looking at this issue....

Comment: Even though you don't think it is relevant, could you please post the OpenDataSource code? Word has several ways to connect to Access databases and if, for example, your application used ODBC to do it, you might need to change or recreate the relevant ODBC DSN.

Comment: @slightlysnarky..........The person I have been helping is out of town but I'll see what I can do to get the code.  Thanks for your help.....

Comment: Another few questions that might help someone work out what's wrong. Can you open the Access DB in Access (or is it something you never need to modify?)? You suggest it is called "123C548eS.com", which would be unusual for an Access DB. Is it actually a .mdb or .accdb? Sometimes Office does use a different extension for temporary Access DB files. Was there a workgroup database associated with the database (that's old tech., but if there was one, it might not have been copied over and you might have to fix up some references).

Comment: It's not evident that this has anything to do with VBA - especially given that you haven't posted any VBA code related to the problem. As best I can tell, it's an end-user issue and, as such, is off-topic for StackOverflow.